# php count array where inner value true

Tags: php, arrays

I wish to count the values in the array Course that have the inner value Completed=>true. There are two values when I do a standard count. I have tried is_array and array_filter

```
count($employee['Course']
```

output: 2

```
Course(array)
    0(array)
        id:1
        name:Handling
        CoursesEmployee(array)
            id:1
            employee_id:1
            course_id:1
            completed(true)
     1(array)
         id:3
         name:Induction
         CoursesEmployee(array)
             id:2
             employee_id:1
             course_id:3
             completed(false)
```

Comment: How have you tried `array_filter()` and what was the result?

Comment: Yes I got 2 returned echo count(array_filter($course));

Comment: result of var_dump ?

Comment: `array_filter()` takes an optional argument to specify a function that gets called for each element in your array. I'd suggest you start with that.

Comment: sorry no, it is the array structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using PHP 5.3 or higher, you may accomplish it via a single expression:

```
count(
  array_filter(
    $employee['Course'], 
    function($item){return $item['CoursesEmployee']['completed'];} 
  )
)
```

See docs on [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) and [anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php).

Comment: thank you, I have a better understanding of array_filter

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `array_reduce`, which can grind an array down to a single result.

```
array_reduce( $employee['Course'], function( $carry, $item ) { 
  return $carry + (bool)$item['CoursesEmployee']['completed'] ) { 
}, 0 );
```

Using the fact that booleans have an int value of 0 for false or 1 for true.

Docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php